# Windows 10 Explorer is very slow when first opened/used

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Windows 10 Explorer is very slow when first used after reboot.
For instance copy/paste or move a file lasts a minute.
Right click mouse (to call context menu) - a minute.

But only first time. If I do it again - no delay.

NVMe new SSD harddrivejust installed and cloned Windows from the old drive didn't change the situation.
(No, that was not the reason of changing a disk but there were slight hope)

There is no antivirus on PC. I already disabled "Windows Search" service.
Thanks if you can advise what can be checked to find/fix an issue.

Comment: You don't give details about the size of the file being copied and between which devices.

Comment: Look for old or conflicting context programs (32 bit context programs should not be used),   Use Nirsoft Shell View to help locate

Comment: After rebooting Windows, or awaking from Hibernation, I find *everything*, every application, is deplorably lethargic. This improves after a few minutes. There are a number of reasons this might occur, e.g., Defender scanning files (BTW, I do **not** recommend running Windows without antivirus), Search indexing, looking for updates, rebuilding icons, etc. Two work-arounds: uses Sleep while plugged in, or switch to another OS, e.g. Linux. It takes Ubuntu, on this PC, about 2 minutes to reboot, vs. 7 for Windows, and once booted, Ubuntu has no slowdown.

Comment: Are there any network drives connected? They can take some time to reconnect.

Comment: If you start Task Explorer (ctrl+shift+esc) and sort by CPU, does anything stand out as using a lot of CPU time while Explorer is being slow?

Comment: Third party context menu items can cause the Windows Shell to be lethargic in that way, as can a whole host of other things. Assuming there's at least 8GB of RAM and Windows Defender has always been enabled, with scans returning no malware, do a repair install by extracting a Windows install ISO to a folder and running Windows Setup _while booted to Windows_, choosing to keep everything _(do not boot from a Windows Install USB to install Windows)_. That will resolve the issue, and if it comes back, make note of what was done prior to the last reboot, such as any program installed/updated.

Answer (score 0):

How big are the files? I have a relatively new NVMe SSD, and copying large files, say a 5 gig ISO, takes a while. Large files do take ages to copy. If the files are only Megabytes (MB) or Kilobytes (KB) in size, something might be astray....

If they are small files, try Windows Defender (a built-in entry level antivirus), just search "Windows Defender" in the start menu.

Comment: No. it is no a matter of fil sizes. The (kind of) freezing begins when a new directory is opened or a file selected and I click on right button of mouse to open context menu. 

I already disabled "Windows Search" . No change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the solution will be useful for many users.
But it looks like the problem was in a program TortoiseGit which I had installed.
I think this program was monitoring the filesystem too much.
Anyhow after I deleted it everything became OK.